# UIButton image dimension different from original

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a 40x40 button and in it I wanted to place an image of 20x20 dimension in the center. Here is what I did.

1. Set the content mode to center.(No scaling)
2. Assigned the image as the 'image' property of the button.

But when I run the program and check the image's dimension, it is different. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: ca you post the differ image for better understanding to answer?

Answer (score 0):

In `UIButton` class, you've `image` and `backgroundImage` properties which have different behaviour when you set an image. You can use one of the 2 depending on what you want to do.

Comment: I want to see the image just as it is. No scaling

Answer (score 0):

In my case If I just set the image property of the button,The image will be in the center.

Check these things:

```
1.Make sure you set the *image* ,not the *backgroundImage*.
2.Make sure the size of your image assets is smaller than the button's size.
3.Er...I just know two things...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the Custom UIButton
2. Create the UIImageView and add it as subview of custom UIButton.

Please refer the below code snippet, it will add the image in centre of button.

```
-(void)addImageInCenterForButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SettingIcon"]];
    CGRect imgRect = button.bounds;
    imgRect.size.width = 20;
    imgRect.size.height = 20;
    imgRect.origin.x = (button.bounds.size.width - imgRect.size.width) / 2;
    imgRect.origin.y = (button.bounds.size.height - imgRect.size.height) / 2;
    imgView.frame = imgRect;

    [button addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Comment: I have already done this as a work around. I want to know why the image is not appearing properly when we are adding it as the button's image property.

Comment: Because imageView is readonly. @property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UIImageView *imageView

Comment: Please understand the question.. the image is getting added but the dimension is getting changed

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope it helps..

my image is of 20x20 dimension,and if i change the size of button it looks same and its also in the center of a button..

```
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40 ,40)];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ok"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[btn setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```